# Laravel: how does it register the configuration service?

Tags: php, laravel

How does Laravel register the configuration service (the one handling `Config` facade and `config()` helper)? I can't find it anywhere in `config/app.php @ providers` and documentation says nothing about its registration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- All the config methods(get, set, has..) are located in `Illuminate\Config\Repository` and this class implements `Illuminate\Contracts\Config\Repository` interface.
- This class and interface is located in `Illuminate\Foundation\Application` which is the container of application please check [registerCoreContainerAliases](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/7.x/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Application.php#L1210).
- After the registration, the framework needs to initialize/load configurations and `Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\LoadConfiguration` is responsible for this. Please check `bootstrap` and `loadConfigurationFiles` [methods](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/7.x/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Bootstrap/LoadConfiguration.php#L39)
- The class responsible for registration is used in `Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel`.

This class is used in `Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel`, here is the list of bootstrappers.

```
// list of framework related bootstrappers to make application ready when application is up
protected $bootstrappers = [
    \Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\LoadEnvironmentVariables::class,
    \Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\LoadConfiguration::class,
    \Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\HandleExceptions::class,
    \Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\RegisterFacades::class,
    \Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\RegisterProviders::class,
    \Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\BootProviders::class,
];
```

- The Config facade is just a static proxy between you and container.
- config helper is just using service locator to get `config` instance out of bind services.