# How to use route helper in config file

Tags: php, laravel, routes, helper

So i have a config file called `services.php` with content like

```
[
    'facebook' => [ 'url' => 'https://...']
]
```

But i want to have it like this:

```
[
    'facebook' => [ 'url' => url(route('socialite-callback', ['provider' => 'facebook']))]
]
```

However `tinker` with this like of code will report:

```
Argument 2 passed to Illuminate\Routing\UrlGenerator::__construct() must be an instance of Illuminate\Http\Request, null given, called in /laravel/justitalianwine_ecommerce/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/RoutingServiceProvider.php on line 68
```

But if i use the first like, and then open `tinker` and paste this:

```
url(route('socialite-callback', ['provider' => 'facebook']))
```

it works fine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I explained how the configs are loaded [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62349824/2188922).

The reason you are getting this error is "probably" that helper methods are loaded/bootstrapped after the configuration is loaded.

One way to do it would be using `RouteServiceProvider` to initialize/set the config for these type usages that you need.

```
class RouteServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    // other methods and fields...

    public function map()
    {
        $this->mapApiRoutes();
        $this->mapWebRoutes();
        $this->mapServiceRoutes();
    }

    protected function mapServiceRoutes()
    {
        config()->set('services.facebook.url', url(route('socialite-callback', ['provider' => 'facebook'])));
    }
}
```

Edit:

Also there is 5+ years old issue in [github](https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/7671) mentioning a similar case to yours.

Comment: is this allowed or is considered "changing a framework file" and so it's not recommended?

Comment: I don't think it is "changing a framework" file, you can create your ServiceProvider or make additions to existing ServiceProviders such as Application, Route or EventServiceProviders. It is perfectly "allowed". @Berto99